# Ruby's Net::HTTP doesn't get the right answer from google OAuth server

Tags: ruby, curl, net-http

I'm writing a small cli tool, that should check my calendar and do some stuff according to my appointments.
I'm struggling a little bit with the OAuth2 authentication. I've checked the scope and the client_id with the curl tool like this:

```
curl -d "client_id=12345...&scope=scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code
```

This way, I get the right response.

```
{
 "device_code" : "somestuff",
 "user_code" : "otherstuff",
 "verification_url" : "http://www.google.com/device",
 "expires_in" : 1800,
 "interval" : 5
}
```

But, when I try to use Net::HTTP in Ruby I just get HTTP state 200. I've done it this way:

```
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {'client_id' =>'1234....apps.googleusercontent.com', 'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly' })
```

If I check the res variable afterwards I get the state 302, but I guess this is correct.
Can someone tell me what I'm, doing wrong so I don't get the JSON response? Should I try something different than Net::HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res` is a variable containing all the response data, not just the text of the response. If you `puts res.body` after your `post_form()` call, you should find your JSON (which you can parse with the [`JSON`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) module).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've tried this, but it says, that the variable is empty (nil). After I tried to access res.body it worked. Thanks